# Optimize nested for loop in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have following r code. It has nested for loops. I want to replace the number with NA if the i+3 row value is zero. It works fine for small datasets, however, for large datasets, it hangs. I am assuming the nested for loops are not the efficient way to achieve it. Could someone help suggest enhancing the code, preferably tidyverse library?

```
x <- data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3,2,1,3),
                c2=c(4,5,6,2,3,4),
                c3=c(7,8,9,7,1,6),
                c4=c(4,0,9,1,5,0),
                c5=c(3,8,0,7,3,6),
                c6=c(2,8,5,0,5,7),
                row.names = c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6"))

for( i in 1:nrow(x)){
  for(j in 1:3){
    if (x[i, j+3] == 0){
      x[i, j] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

Output: x

```
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
r1  1  4  7  4  3  2
r2 NA  5  8  0  8  8
r3  3 NA  9  9  0  5
r4  2  2 NA  1  7  0
r5  1  3  1  5  3  5
r6 NA  4  6  0  6  7
```

Comment: You're likely to see performance increases by (1) converting the data.frame to a matrix (2) swapping the i and j loops (data is laid out in memory by column, so it is faster to iterate through all entries in a column in the inner-most loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop over rows is not necessary, you can vectorize the outer loop with `ifelse`:

```
x[1:3] <- lapply(1:3, function(n) ifelse(x[[n+3]] == 0, NA, x[[n]]))
x
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
#r1  1  4  7  4  3  2
#r2 NA  5  8  0  8  8
#r3  3 NA  9  9  0  5
#r4  2  2 NA  1  7  0
#r5  1  3  1  5  3  5
#r6 NA  4  6  0  6  7
```

---

Or simpler method you can modify the first three columns based on the last three columns by doing boolean indexing and assignment:

```
x[1:3][x[4:6] == 0] <- NA
x
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
#r1  1  4  7  4  3  2
#r2 NA  5  8  0  8  8
#r3  3 NA  9  9  0  5
#r4  2  2 NA  1  7  0
#r5  1  3  1  5  3  5
#r6 NA  4  6  0  6  7
```

Comment: I'm wondering if speed is really the goal whether or not a matrix would be best?

Comment: yes i am looking for best speed possible because the actual dataset could be few 10 million rows.

Comment: @zacdav I'd say whether a data frame or matrix depends on what OP wants to do with it later.

Comment: matrix seems much faster on my testing, using `xm = as.matrix(x)` with `xm[ ,1:3][xm[, 4:6] == 0] <- NA`

Comment: @zacdav That's indeed true. But keep in mind you have to convert a big data frame to matrix firstly, which is costly.